# Python decode issue with PySerial data

Tags: python, hex, ascii, pyserial

I have a Python script reading a serial port and I am receiving data from my serial port but the data comes in I believe hex format.

Here is my code:

```
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial(
   port='COM4',\
   baudrate=9600,\
   parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,\
   stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,\
   bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,\
    timeout=3)

counter=0

while 1:
 x=ser.readline()
 print (x)
```

Here is the data I am getting back from the serial port:
`b'\x82P0000000\xb1\x035\xb2\x82P0000000\xb1\x035\xb2\x82P0000000\xb1\x035\xb2'`

The data is supposed to be in ASCII but I am new to Python and am kind of stuck. I have tried to use decode() in different ways but no luck.

If someone can point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know what the string is supposed to be?

Comment: unfortunately I don't. It should be a number from my knowledge, possibly some letters in front of it. EXA: PLU0001 or PLU1